# Search across relational table with a custom query builder giving null in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table `purchases` and another table `purchase_company_details` and I want to search for data in get record where either of them have the data. But I am getting null if I give a vary related data to either oi column.

e.g: I am searching data in `po_no`  column in `purchase` table and `name`  column in `purchase_company_details`. Now if I search for `PO`, I get data as something in `name` column have `po` value. but if I send `PO-` I get null data as `PO-` exist in 'po_no`but not in`name ` column.'

below is the log of from `DB::getQueryLog()`

```
[2023-02-21 14:20:09] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select count(*) as aggregate from "purchases" where "po_no"::text like ? and exists (select * from "purchase_company_details" where "purchases"."id" = "purchase_company_details"."purchase_id" and "name"::text like ?)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '%PO-07%',
      1 => '%PO-07%',
    ),
    'time' => 4.63,
  ),
)
```

Below is the query in the URL:

```
api/v1/purchase?page=1&order_column=id&order_direction=desc&filter_match=or&f[1][column]=po_no&f[1][operator]=contains&f[1][query_1]=PO-&f[2][column]=seller_details.name&f[2][operator]=contains&f[2][query_1]=PO
```

Query Builder Code:

```
...
class CustomQueryBuilder
{

    protected $defaultFilterMatch = 'and';

    public function apply($query, $data)
    {
        return $query->when(isset($data['f']), function ($query) use ($data) {
            foreach ($data['f'] as $filter) {
                $this->applyFilter($filter, $query, $data);
            }
        });
    }

    protected function applyFilter($filter, $query, $data)
    {
        $filter['match'] = $data['filter_match'] ?: $this->defaultFilterMatch;
        if (strpos($filter['column'], '.') !== false) {
            // nested column
            list($relation, $relatedColumn) = explode('.', $filter['column']);
            $filter['column'] = $relatedColumn;
            $filter['match'] = 'and';

            $query->whereHas($relation, function ($q) use ($filter) {
                $this->{camel_case($filter['operator'])}($filter, $q);
            });
        } else {
            // normal column
            $this->{camel_case($filter['operator'])}($filter, $query);
        }
    }

...
// contains:q1
    protected function contains($filter, $query)
    {
        return $query->where($filter['column'], 'like', '%' . $filter['query_1'] . '%', $filter['match']);
    }

...

}
```

I think this is more than enough information to start with. If I am searching for one `param` then it works. I want the search field to be able to look in more than one column for a match.

also posted on laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/search-across-relational-table-with-a-custom-query-builder-giving-null

Comment: You may want to use the `orWhere` method https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Comment: @Coola In `CustomQueryBuilder` where would I have to make that change? as you can see that the `f` represent the number of condition. and here we have 2 table. `$filter['match']` does add or. but how to make it use orWhere instead of where ...

Comment: Its a little difficult to parse through what your CustomQueryBuilder Class is doing. Could you add comments to what the different methods are doing. For example, when does the `contains()` method get called?